# How to treat weekend data in a financial panel dataset

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I'm writing a paper on how the European stock market liquidity has been affected by the pandemic. I'm using daily stock data for 5 countries which doesn't include any weekend data. This financial data includes a dependent liquidity measure and independent variables like returns,market cap,... . I end up with 100 stocks from 01/03/2021 to 30/12/2022 To control for the pandemic i'm using the daily growth in cumulative cases, deaths, and vaccinations for each country. These pandemic variables have been calculated as *ln(V(j,t)/V(j,t-1))* where *V* stands for the value of either cumulative cases, deaths, or vaccinations in country *j* for day *t*.

I'm using a stacked time series approach in Excel where all the individual stocks are listed under eachother with the same dates for each stock. So all stocks start at 01/03/2021 and end at 30/12/2022. I remove all financial data points for each stock that doesn't have a value for the liquidity measure. So for example if stock A doesn't have an observation for the liquidity measure on day 01/05/2021 I remove the obeservation for all independent variables, but I keep the date in the dataset, so the date would just be empty. If stock B doesn't have a value for the liquidity measure for day 31/10/2022 I delete all independent observations for that day, but keep 31/10/2022 in the dataset as empty. These removed variables do show up as missing datapoints in Gretl (used econometrics program).

Now my main question is, as the stock markets do not provide any data in the weekends or holidays but the pandemic data does have values for weekends. What can I best do to not omit this weekend data for the pandemic, as deleting the observations as I have done with the financial data does remove important information on the growth of the pandemic variables.

Thank you in advance. If I need to elaborate more on anything, please ask.

Kind Regards.